# SSD stalls my Windows installation

Tags: ssd, performance

I've just installed Windows 2003 Server on a Corsair CMFSSD-64N1 64GB SSD and I am quite baffled from the outcome... This is the slowest experience I've ever had with my computer. When running a single program (ie: chrome) everything works fine. But the moment I start 3-4 applications my system starts to stall. I can't even scroll a web page in chrome for 2-10 seconds... During installations computer becomes almost unusable. I've never experienced something like this before. Any thoughts or ideas?

**Edit:
The problem seems to be directly related to the number of operations on the drive for some reason.**

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had scrolling problems in web browsers before, which were usually related to video drivers. Do you have all of the drivers installed and updated?

---

**Update**

It seems that this model uses a jmicron controller which is related to the studding. User [reviews on newegg](http://www.newegg.ca/Product/ProductReview.aspx?Item=N82E16820233086) are having the same problem with this particular drive, saying that it is not good at multitasking whatsoever:

> Pros: Its fast with one application at
> a time. Windows loads very fast
> compared to the raptor I had before it
> died :(, also applications load
> quickly .
>
> Cons: Does not multitask very well at
> all. At first I thought it was my ram
> but tested with occt and memtest86 and
> it passed both test. Also tested the
> cpu and it passed as well. I google it
> to see if any other people had the
> same problem and they did. Had I know
> this I would of went for a raptor
> instead.
>
> Other Thoughts: When I multitask the
> comp just gets stuck for about 20 sec
> and then it will work fine but then it
> will do it again, the problem happens
> randomly, one minute its fine then the
> other its not. Not happy with this
> purchase.

> Pros: inexpensive ssd
>
> Cons: jmicron controller causes
> studding just like others have
> reported. Google jmicron and studding
> and you'll see a bunch!
>
> Other Thoughts: I tried all the tweeks
> i could find (removing indexing
> programs , removing cache on the
> browser , and even lowering the
> virtual memory) still studded.

Comment: I had the some OS with the same drivers and applications on the same machine... The only thing changed is the SSD drive. Scrolling was just an example, even "Start" button won't work during these stalls

Comment: The problem seems to be directly related to the number of operations on the drive for some reason.

Comment: seems to be common with this drive, updated answer.

Comment: it's a MLC SSD, which is a NO NO, if you want performance. get a SLC SSD instead.

Comment: I am very disappointed with my purchase :(